# How to apply TF-IDF on pandas column based on colon delimiter in text data

Tags: python, pandas, tfidfvectorizer

I have a column in pandas dataframe where I capture a visitor's journey. I want to implement TF-IDF on this text column. Here is the sample data -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [10, 11, 12]
                   , 'pagename': ['home:cart:checkout:buy:home','home:cart:cart:home','home:account:home']})
```

Below is how `df` looks like -
[image]

I want to now apply `tf-idf` technique where my words are separated by a delimiter like `:` . When I try below code, it does not work -

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf_idf_model =  TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, use_idf=True,token_pattern=':')
tf_idf_df = tf_idf_model.fit_transform(df['pagename'])
```

tf_idf_model.get_feature_names() prints out `[':']`

How can I achieve tf-idf on this pagename column so that in my output I get columns such as `home`, `cart`, `account`, `checkout` , `buy` with their corresponding weights?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out -

I had to use a custom tokenizer to solve this problem -

Here is my code that works now -

```
def tokens(x): return x.split(':')
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer( tokenizer=tokens 
                            ,use_idf=True
                            , smooth_idf=True
                            , min_df = 100
                            , stop_words = 'english'
                            , max_features = 10
                            , sublinear_tf=False)
```

And then I can compute the transformed data like this below -

```
tf_idf_matrix = pd.DataFrame(
    tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['pagename']).toarray(), 
    columns=tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()
)
```

Here is the final output -

[image]